# Inserting data in child table using Linq to sql (3 tier Architecture)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I am stuck at a simple code in asp.net
I want to insert simple string values to 1 Parent Table (Accounts) and 1 Child Table(Applicant_bio).
Now here's the thing, I am able to put data in Parent table but when I try to access the Child table, it gives me the following error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint linq to sql
```

I have explicitly set the values of both Primary Keys to match so there is no conflict, as the tables have a 1 to 1 relation.
Here's My code:

```
public string Retreive_Applicants(Applicant_list user_details)
        {
            newDatabaseDataContext connection = new newDatabaseDataContext();
            //Create a new instance of the applicant object
           account account = new account();
           account.account_id = 1;
           account.account_type = "Applicant";
           account.account_description = "";
           account.account_title = user_details.account_title;
           account.account_password = user_details.account_password;
           connection.accounts.InsertOnSubmit(account);
           connection.SubmitChanges();



           account.applicant_bio= new applicant_bio();
           account.applicant_bio.account_id = account.account_id; //Here's Where I have explicitly set the account id of applicant_bio to account_id of accounts table just created
           account.applicant_bio.applicant_name = user_details.applicant_name;
           account.applicant_bio.applicant_age = user_details.applicant_age;
           account.applicant_bio.applicant_cnic = user_details.applicant_cnic;
           connection.applicant_bios.InsertOnSubmit(account.applicant_bio);
           connection.SubmitChanges(); //Here's where the error occurs
            return "success";
        }
```

Here's the Database Details
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzboS.png)

Comment: It seems you are inserting a key in child table which is not in parent table,try to print values and see

Comment: @TheGameiswar have print both object values and they returned same values i.e. account.account_id and account.applicant_bio.account_id return the same values

Comment: It would help if you also gave the db definition of both tables.

Comment: @RoyFalk I have added an image to the original post, check it out

Comment: I wrote this comment in my role as reviewer for the site and in order to improve the quality of the question and so attract people with the knowledge to help you. Alas, SQL was never something I knew well. However, after looking at the picture, this isn't as good as the textual definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because linq understand that with applicant_bio you are trying to save also a new account objet that already exist, try saving both it works this way:

```
public string Retreive_Applicants(Applicant_list user_details)
        {
            newDatabaseDataContext connection = new newDatabaseDataContext();
            //Create a new instance of the applicant object
           account account = new account();
           account.account_id = 1;
           account.account_type = "Applicant";
           account.account_description = "";
           account.account_title = user_details.account_title;
           account.account_password = user_details.account_password;

           account.applicant_bio= new applicant_bio();
           //You dont need this line any more
           //account.applicant_bio.account_id = account.account_id; 
           account.applicant_bio.applicant_name = user_details.applicant_name;
           account.applicant_bio.applicant_age = user_details.applicant_age;
           account.applicant_bio.applicant_cnic = user_details.applicant_cnic;           
           connection.accounts.InsertOnSubmit(account);
           connection.SubmitChanges();
            return "success";
        }
```

Comment: I have done this, still doesn't work, I also want to add that I have created a relation between `account_id` in `accounts` table and `applicant_id` in `applicant_bio` table (1 to 1). I also have tried to set `account_id` as primary key of both tables but still it gives me a foreign key error. However, I can successfully enter the data if I create a 1 to Many relationship between `account_id` in `accounts` table (Parent) and `account_id` in `applicant_bio` table (Child)